# Why is Parse PFObject response borked?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am starting a new project on Parse.

I am trying to retrieve my own properties on a custom class PFObject being returned from a query. I'm using [object objectForKey:@"key"] and it isn't working. I logged the description of the object I was getting back from the query and it's format is:

```
<Horse: 0x7f93e9c7e240, objectId: gLqeyEfOr6, localId: (null)> {
    hidden = 0;
    visibleName = "Horsey";
}
```

Notice that "hidden" and "visibleName" have been encapsulated by { }'s . This seems to be my issue. Why is this format happening to my custom properties? How do I get the data for keys "hidden" and "visibleName" out of my PFObject?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a PFObject directly as a dictionary - the {} is just added by the description method (which is the method that gets invoked when you NSLog the object as a string) to indicate a dictionary. What you have should work. You can also use the more compact notation -

```
NSString *visibleName=myPFObject[@"visibleName"];
NSNumber *hidden=myPFObject[@"hidden"];
```

What results are you getting when you say "it doesn't work"?